# Wanted [ Example of SQL transactions ]

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, transactions

I am fairly new to SQL. Currently I am trying to understand transactions and I am getting pretty lost. So I would like if you could just show me few examples of SQL transactions.

What I think I have right is that the transactions are usually implemented with the DBM software which then pretty much builds them together based on what I do in the user interface.

So, for example if I want to delete multiple rows how would the transaction look like?
Would it be like this:

1. SAVEPOINT sp1;
2. DELETE FROM customers
   WHERE fname = “James” AND lname = “Belik
3. COMMIT;
4. SAVEPOINT sp2;
5. DELETE FROM customers
   WHERE fname = “James” AND lname = “Belik;
6. COMMIT;

Or if not how would it be? And also where does the SET TRANSACTION go?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged your question for SQL (generic), MySQL, and Access, and each "flavour" of SQL may have its own specific syntax (check the relevant documentation, e.g., for MySQL look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)). However, a generic example would be

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE BankAccount SET Balance=Balance-5 WHERE Owner='James';
UPDATE BankAccount SET Balance=Balance+5 WHERE Owner='Gord';
COMMIT;
```

If the second UPDATE statement fails then the entire transaction is "rolled back" and both account balances remain unchanged. Only if *both* UPDATES succeed does the $5 get transferred from your account to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are used when you want an entire series of SQL statements to succeed.  If any part of the series fails, the database is rolled back to the state prior to the BEGIN TRANSACTION.  You wrap the entire sequence of SQL statements in a transaction.

The usual example is that of a transfer between bank accounts.  To do that, I have to debit one account by an amount, and credit another account by the same amount.  Both operations must succeed, because if only one succeeds, then the transfer won't balance.  For example, if the credit succeeds but the debit fails, someone got free money.

Comment: I understand the theory. I just want to see the layout of the transaction's control commands around the queries :/ Thanks anyway.